# Using Form View to insert image into database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem to insert the image into the database. My image is failed to insert into the database.

In my .aspx file, I have this code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="test" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" InsertMethod="test_InsertItem" ItemType="Inventory.Models.pic" DataKeyNames="Id">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("picture") %>' Height = "150" Width = "150" /><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" /><br /><br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create" CommandName="Insert"/><br /><br />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Then I have these in my .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)test.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    Image Image1 = (Image)test.FindControl("Image1");

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

            Image1.ImageUrl = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {

         }
    }
}

public void test_InsertItem()
{
    pic item = new pic();
    TryUpdateModel(item);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TestEntities _db = new TestEntities();
        _db.pics.Add(item);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And this as my database code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pic]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [picture] IMAGE NULL
)
```

It works well when I using textbox to save the text into the database but when comes to image it's gone wrong. I wish to store the whole image into the database but not the image URL. How can I do that?

Comment: Try to save only file paths into your database. Store images in disk and location to the file in your database.

Comment: But if i store the file paths into database, when other computer access to database, they only retrieve the path but not the image itself and the image cannot show due to i retrieve the path

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `image` type, you should be using `varbinary` instead.  The `image` type will be removed in future version.  You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

As for you code, it'll be a bit easier.

```
var image = File.ReadAllBytes(path-to-image);
```

Then your entity should have corresponding `byte[]` which will allow you to place into the database.  You cannot use `FileStream` either for Entity Framework it will simply leverage a `varbinary` unless something has changed.